# Magento2 how to add non category drop down menu in frontend

Tags: magento-2.1, magento-2.1.3, topmenu, link, custom-menu

Dears,

how to add non-category drop-down menu in fronted

Need Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.magewallet.com/blog/magento-2/add-non-category-links-navigation-menu-magento-2/#comment-899 plz read this how to create non catagory module

mor then one noncatagory menu creation: http://alextimmer.net/blog/development/add-non-category-menu-items-to-a-magento-2-shop/

Comment: The URL may become broken or inaccessible. When that happens, it will render this answer useful. Maybe you can consider putting a full answer and reference the actual  source to give them credit.